# Implication, conjunction and disjunction distributivity problems

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have proven using theorems that implication is left distributive over conjunction:

$ x \rightarrow (y \land z) \equiv ( x \rightarrow y ) \land ( x \rightarrow z ) $

Proof:

$ x \rightarrow (y \land z)
\\
\equiv
\\
\neg x \lor ( y \land z )
\\
\equiv
\\
( \neg x \lor y ) \land ( \neg x \lor z )
\\
\equiv
\\
( x \rightarrow y ) \land ( x \rightarrow z ) $

I have also proved that implication is left distributive over disjunction in a similar way. However, I am now struggling to prove:

- whether or not conjunction and disjunction are left distributive over implication

  $ x \land ( y \rightarrow z ) \equiv ( x \land y ) \rightarrow ( x \land z ) $

  $ x \lor ( y \rightarrow z ) \equiv ( x \lor y ) \rightarrow ( x \lor z ) $
- whether or not implication is right distributive over conjunction and disjunction

  $ ( y \land z ) \rightarrow x \equiv ( y \rightarrow x ) \land ( z \rightarrow x ) $  **(EDIT: I think I have proven this one)**

  $ ( y \lor z ) \rightarrow x \equiv ( y \rightarrow x ) \lor ( z \rightarrow x ) $

I would appreciate any help as to where to get started on these proofs, or what theorems I should be looking at to prove them, as well as any advice on how to prove if one of them is NOT​ distributive (i.e. how do I know that one of the above theorems is false without attempting, and failing, to prove it many, many different ways).

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I know that one of the above statements is false without attempting, and failing, to prove it many, many different ways?

You may simply make a truth table for each of these statements, although that's not the most economic way, it's still one of the most straightforward techniques. Let's take for instance the first one, namely,

$$x \land ( y \to z ) \equiv ( x \land y ) \to ( x \land z ),$$

which we'll call $\small\tt P_1$. We have:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
{}
\small  \color{green}{x} &\small  \color{green}{y} &\small  \color{green}{z} &\small  y\to z &\small  x\land(y\to z) &\small  x\land y &\small  x\land z &\small  (x\land y)\to(x\land z) &\small   \tt P_\color{black}{1} \\ \hline
{}
\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1}  \\ \hline
\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} \\ \hline
\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} \\ \hline
\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} \\ \hline
\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} \\ \hline
\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} \\ \hline
\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} \\ \hline
\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} &\small  \color{royalblue}{1} &\small  \color{#C00}{0} \\ \hline
\end{array} 
$$

Hence $\small\tt P_1$ is certainly not a tautology. The use of a truth table is unnecessary if we observe from the beginning that we do not have an equivalence when $x$ is false. You can do the same for the remaining ones,
$$\begin{align}
x \lor ( y \to z ) &\equiv ( x \lor y ) \to ( x \lor z ),
\\
( y \lor z ) \to x &\equiv ( y \to x ) \lor ( z \to x ),
\end{align}$$
which we will respectively denote as  [$\small\tt P_2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth+table+%28x+OR+%28+y+IMPLIES+z+%29+EQUIVALENT+%28+x+OR+y+%29+IMPLIES+%28+x+OR+z+%29%29) and [$\small\tt P_3$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth+table+%28%28%28y+OR+z%29+IMPLIES+x%29+EQUIVALENT+%28%28y+IMPLIES+x%29+OR+%28z+IMPLIES+x%29%29%29). You'll see that $\small\tt P_2$ is the only tautology.

Now, to show that this is indeed the case $-$ without relying on a truth table $-$ we'll start with the RHS,

$$\begin{align}
(y\to x)\lor(z\to x) & \equiv (\lnot y\lor x)\lor(\lnot z\lor x) \\
                     & \equiv (\lnot y\lor\lnot z)\lor x         \\
                     & \equiv \lnot(y\land z)\lor x              \\
                     & \equiv (y\land z)\to x. \tag*{$\small\square$}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Prove of the above equation
p -> (q ^ r)  <-> (p -> q) ^ (p -> r)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7im1.jpg